# Show 2nd div when radio button checked

Tags: javascript, html, css, radio-button

Im trying to make a contact form where people will check either "one way" ticket or "roundtrip".

The first "one way" is checked when user reach the contact form and one(1) date field is shown, but if "roundtrip" is checked i want a 2nd date field to be shown with a return date.

Any ideas?

Comment: I suggest you take a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6017558/checkbox-checked-or-unchecked-with-jquery-and-mysql
With an Ajax call based on whether the box is checked or unchecked, you can make the second field appear or disappear.

Comment: I really would like to leave Ajax outside. Im just trying to have a div with a 2nd date field to be hidden as long as the first radio button is checked. So all I want is some type of js that uses onchange or something to change from display:none to display:block.

Comment: I agree Ajax is not necessary in your case, javascript would be much better.

Comment: As answered... http://stackoverflow.com/a/5137316/1093284 shows a "checkbox influences the visibility of two inputs" example. No ajax, just jQuery in beautiful action. ;)

Comment: By the way, have you attempted anything yet or done any research on the problem?  It's frowned upon to ask questions like this (beginner, common task things) without some evidence that you've attempted something and gotten stuck.

Comment: AlexMA. Yes I've tried some different things but I'm not as pro on this as u seem to be thats why I asked. Don't know why I have to show u but here u go. Tried first with onclick and this, and it didnt work, was i wrong to ask for help? <script type = "text/javascript">
function show(which) {
if (which == 1) {
document.getElementById("date").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("date_return").style.display = "none";
}
else {
document.getElementById("date").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("date_return").style.display = "block";
}
}
</script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply observe the onchange event for the radio button. When it reaches you can check weather single trip or round trip is selected and then show / hide the div with the return date fields.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script>
    function hdl_change(e) {
        document.getElementById('date2').style.visibility = 
            e.checked && e.id == 'opt_2' ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="myForm">
  <input id="opt_1" type="radio" name="trip" value="oneway" onchange="hdl_change(this)"> One way<br>
  <input id="opt_2" type="radio" name="trip" value="round" onchange="hdl_change(this)"> Roundtrip<br>
</form>
<div id="date1"> date 1 stuff ...</div>
<div id="date2" style="visibility:hidden">  date 2 stuff ...</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Fabian! Just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use *javascript* and *on-event* handlers to accomplish that, as such *dependent/binding* functionality doesn't come with the regular html *form* elements (To avoid confusion: same goes for it's potential children).

This answer will give you a pretty good hint how to do it as it answers a question related to a similar problem/request: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5137316/1093284

**Update:**

As you don't seem very experienced, here's a most simplistic example:

```
<!-- include jquery.js library first  (http://jquery.com/) -->
<script src="jquery.js"></script>

<!-- then work the magic -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#inputB').hide;

    $('#checkboxA').click(
        function(e){
                $('#inputA').show;
                $('#inputB').hide;
        });
    $('#checkboxB').click(
        function(e){
                $('#inputB').show;
                $('#inputA').hide;
        });
});
</script>
```

And if you're fit enough to go pro with jQuery, check the other answer here on this page at https://stackoverflow.com/a/11743381/1093284

Last but not least, I think the answer here at https://stackoverflow.com/a/11743482/1093284 provides the best solution, as it's small and does not require a full-blown 32kb javascript library. On the other hand, inline javascript is actually a no-go. Whatever... it's the users that count and they will prefer a quicker-loading page over nicely coded stuff behind the curtains.